# activate SSL for Mesh / Docker

Tags: docker, gentics-mesh

I have set up the docker container for mesh 
https://hub.docker.com/r/gentics/mesh/

I have tried to configure SSL as mentioned in the [docs](https://getmesh.io/docs/beta/administration-guide.html#_https_ssl).

```
httpServer:
  port: 8080
  host: "0.0.0.0"
  ssl: true
  cerPath: "config/cert.pem"
  keyPath: "config/key.pem"
  corsAllowedOriginPattern: ""
  corsAllowCredentials: false
  enableCors: false
```

The settings have no impact. I cannot access mesh in the browser with SSL.
The docker logs show no indication concerning SSL.

Any ideas how to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use Gentics Mesh 0.23.0 or newer. That version supports SSL.